# Can you differentiate the length of a function?

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, derivatives

I came across a tricky issue while setting up an optimization problem.  Is it possible to differentiate $len^2(f(x)_B)$, the squared length of some function $f(x)$ under some basis $B$?

I know this involves summing the squares of the quantities of each element of the basis used to construct the function, but I'm not sure how to express this fact in a form that could be differentiated.

Comment: Differentiate with respect to ... what?

Comment: To $x$, ultimately I want to extend the operation to two variables, but I doubt that will be much harder.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the chain rule:

$$L^2(f(x)) \implies 2L(f(x))\dfrac{dL}{df}\dfrac{df}{dx}$$

Comment: Are you sure that is correct? Should't the length be differentiated with respect to $f$ here?

Comment: @DevashishKaushik Thank you for the comment!

Comment: No problem ! :)

Comment: @MachineLearner My trouble is with the $\frac{dL}{df}$ factor.  How would I expend that part?

Comment: @user10478: Wherever you have $u=f(x)$ in the expression think of it as one quantity and differentiate it as you would normally differentiate $L(u)$.

Comment: Eh, I think the problem is that I've asked the wrong question entirely.  I'll accept this answer and ask a new one with more context.